# Chart is displayed but i get ReferenceError: chart is not defined in console (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In my console window I get *ReferenceError: chart is not defined*.

Chart is displayed correct, so it can't be some major issue.

If I remove code written below, error disappear and of course also the chart.

I'm using highcharts.

Any advice?

**JS**

```
getShownTab(); 

            chart.series[0].update({ });

            function getShownTab(){
              $('#chartZoneDisplay').highcharts({
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['1.', '2.', '3.', '4.'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Opravljene meritve'
                        },
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1
                        }],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Kilogrami'
                        },
                        gridLineColor: "#222",
                        labels: {
                            padding: 0,
                        },
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#ccc'
                        },
                        itemHoverStyle: { 
                            color: "#fab700" 
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Telesna',
                        //data: [145, 122.9, 100.5, 105.5],
                        data: [<?php echo $parametri_telesna; ?>],
                        color: "#D1E24D",
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: '300',
                                textOutline: '0px',
                                color: '#ccc'
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        name: 'Pusta',
                        data: [<?php echo $parametri_pusta; ?>],
                        color: "#F99A3B",
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: '300',
                                textOutline: '0px',
                                color: '#ccc'
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    chart: {
                        backgroundColor: '#000'

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Gibanje teže',
                        align: 'left',
                        style: {
                            color: '#fab700'
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
```

Comment: Delete this line `chart.series[0].update({ });`. You are trying to access an undefined variable.

Comment: @morganfree Tnx. Looks like the problem is solved.